# "No numeric types to aggregate" after groupby and mean

Tags: python, pandas

I'm dealing with time series and try to write function to calculation monthly average of data. Here are some function for prepare:

```
import datetime
import numpy as numpy
def date_range_0(start,end):

    dates = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=i) 
            for i in range((end-start).days+1)]
    return numpy.array(dates)
def date_range_1(start,days):
    #days should be an interger

    return date_range_0(start,start+datetime.timedelta(days-1))

x=date_range_1(datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 17),4)
```

x, the output is a simple time list:

```
array([datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 17, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 18, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 19, 0, 0),
   datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 20, 0, 0)], dtype=object)
```

Then I learn groupby function from http://blog.csdn.net/youngbit007/article/details/54288603
I have tried one example in website above and it works fine:

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'key1':date_range_1(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 17),5),
              'key2': [2015001,2015001,2015001,2015001,2015001],
              'data1': 1+0.1*numpy.arange(1,6)
        })
df
```

gives

```
   data1    key1    key2
0   1.1 2015-01-17  2015001
1   1.2 2015-01-18  2015001
2   1.3 2015-01-19  2015001
3   1.4 2015-01-20  2015001
4   1.5 2015-01-21  2015001
```

and

```
grouped=df['data1'].groupby(df['key2'])
grouped.mean()
```

gives

```
key2
2015001    0.2
Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

Then I try my own example:

```
datedat=numpy.array([date_range_1(datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 17),5),1+0.1*numpy.arange(1,6)]).T
months = [day.month for day in datedat[:,0]]
years = [day.year for day in datedat[:,0]]
datedatF = 
pandas.DataFrame({'key1':datedat[:,0],'key2':list((numpy.array(years)*1000 +numpy.array(months))),'data1':datedat[:,1]})
datedatF
```

which generated

```
   data1    key1    key2
0   1.1 2015-01-17  2015001
1   1.2 2015-01-18  2015001
2   1.3 2015-01-19  2015001
3   1.4 2015-01-20  2015001
4   1.5 2015-01-21  2015001
```

Note this is exactly the very same table as above! so far so good. Then I run:

```
grouped2=datedatF['data1'].groupby(datedatF['key2'])
grouped2.mean()
```

it throw out this:

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-170-f0d2bc225b88> in <module>()
  1 grouped2=datedatF['data1'].groupby(datedatF['key2'])
----> 2 grouped2.mean()

/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in     mean(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1017         nv.validate_groupby_func('mean', args, kwargs)
   1018         try:
-> 1019             return self._cython_agg_general('mean')
   1020         except GroupByError:
   1021             raise

/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in     _cython_agg_general(self, how, numeric_only)
    806 
    807         if len(output) == 0:
--> 808             raise DataError('No numeric types to aggregate')
    809 
    810         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output, names)

DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

ohh..what did I wrong?Why can't I mean the second pandas.DataFrame? It's completely same as the successful example!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You data1 type in your df is object , we need adding `pd.to_numeric`

```
datedatF.dtypes
Out[39]: 
data1            object
key1     datetime64[ns]
key2              int64
dtype: object
grouped2=pd.to_numeric(datedatF['data1']).groupby(datedatF['key2'])
grouped2.mean()
Out[41]: 
key2
2015001    1.3
Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: this is all that was needed to fix my issue with pandas groupby

Answer (score 5):

your `data1` is of `object` (string) dtype:

```
In [396]: datedatF.dtypes
Out[396]:
data1            object   # <--- NOTE!
key1     datetime64[ns]
key2              int64
dtype: object
```

so try this:

```
In [397]: datedatF.assign(data1=pd.to_numeric(datedatF['data1'], errors='coerce')) \
                  .groupby('key2')['data1'].mean()
Out[397]:
key2
2015001    1.3
Name: data1, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

## Group by

```
dictgrp={'Company':'Goog Goog msft msft fb fb'.split(),
         'Person':'Sam Charlie amy vanessa carl sarah'.split(),
         'Sales':'200 130 340 124 243 350'.split()}

df4=pd.DataFrame(data=dictgrp)
print(df4)
  Company   Person Sales
0    Goog      Sam   200
1    Goog  Charlie   130
2    msft      amy   340
3    msft  vanessa   124
4      fb     carl   243
5      fb    sarah   350

grpdf=pd.to_numeric(df4['Sales']).groupby(df4['Company'])
print(grpdf.mean())
    Company
Goog    165.0
fb      296.5
msft    232.0
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```